how can I rotate the ball continuously at a specific angle using flutter_cube?
I've tried several approaches, the only one that worked was using ball.transform.rotate() and using _scene.update(), but when using ball.updateTransform(), the ball no longer rotates and I believe the correct approach is using updateTransform, as it updates the position, rotation and scale. I didn't find a way to constantly rotate the object at a specific angle with updateTransform(), you can see that flutter_cube Quaternion.euler in updateTransform to update the angle:
  void updateTransform() {
    final Matrix4 m = Matrix4.compose(
        position,
        Quaternion.euler(
            radians(rotation.x), radians(rotation.y), radians(rotation.z)),
        scale);
    transform.setFrom(m);
  }

I have the updateBallPosition method, where I wanted to constantly update the rotation of the ball at a specific angle, mainly at diagonal angles, but none of the approaches I tried using updateTransform worked:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_cube/flutter_cube.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Pool'),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: [_Scene()],
        ),
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 13, 104, 250),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _Scene extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SceneState createState() => _SceneState();
}

class _SceneState extends State<_Scene> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late Object ball;
  late Scene _scene;
  bool loaded = false;
  late Ticker _ticker;
  double angle = 45;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _ticker = createTicker((_) => _update());
    _ticker.start();

    ball = Object(fileName: 'assets/ball.obj');
    ball.scale.setValues(1, 1, 1);
  }

  Vector3 calculateAngle(double an) {
    return Vector3(cos(radians(an)), sin(radians(an)), 0);
  }

  void _update() {
    setState(() {
      _updateBallPosition(const Duration(milliseconds: 16));
    });
  }

  void _updateBallPosition(Duration deltaTime) {
    ball.rotation.x += angle; // EXAMPLE
    ball.rotation.y += angle; // EXAMPLE

    ball.updateTransform();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _ticker.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Cube(
          onSceneCreated: (Scene scene) {
            _scene = scene;
            loaded = true;

            scene.world.add(ball);

            scene.camera.fov = 50;
            scene.world.scene!.camera.position.setValues(0, 0, 10);
          },
          interactive: false,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

I've already tried using some methods from the documentation, such as:  applyAxisAngle method(), but I didn't get anything satisfactory
